# Google API - Storing google refresh tokens for multiple accounts

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I would love to know if it is possible to store multiple refresh tokens in the database and use the corresponding token when the user selects an account. A simple scenario is the user wants to upload a youtube video and if his browser has multiple accounts he selects an account and uploads. Here a refresh token is generated and stored in database and this is used in future uploads by the user. But will I be able to map these tokens to an account id or something so that the same user if selects another account, that refresh token could also be stored?

Comment: As " @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 " has said, there is a flow to it. But from your question, I suspect that it is not going to be possible the way you are hoping. YouTube (Google) have a linked DB of users. So on any google page (youtube) it will save your login details, As well as know which one you are currently using. It is doing all the Oauth stuff in the back, which you will not normally have access to. But perhaps someone has an idea that might read the current page data.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Before going further, you may want to check this [documentation for OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) first.

> To begin, obtain OAuth 2.0 client credentials from the Google API
>   Console. Then your client application requests an access token from
>   the Google Authorization Server, extracts a token from the response,
>   and sends the token to the Google API that you want to access. For an
>   interactive demonstration of using OAuth 2.0 with Google (including
>   the option to use your own client credentials), experiment with the
>   [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

You must need to follow 4 basic steps when accessing a Google API using OAuth 2.0,

> 1. Obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials from the Google API Console.
> 2. Obtain an access token from the Google Authorization Server.
> 3. Send the access token to an API.
> 4. Refresh the access token, if necessary.

Here is [an example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/jS9j8ih51jE) of scenario relating to your question.

So, the scenario is, the user want to connect multiple Google accounts and the problem is the first user is the only one who have received a **refresh token** unlike to the rest that only has **access token**.

From there, you will be led to a solution such as [creating the service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) and [OAuth 2.0 Service](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount).

Hope this is the one you are looking for.

Comment: I was actually hoping that there would be some way to retrieve the email that the user has clicked when granting the access, so that I could store that refresh token against his email